# Problems calling fitbounds outside jquery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a Google Map in JavaScript(v3).
I need to show some markers from XML, for which I use jQuery.

Here's the object and function, might save me time explaining:

```
    var VX = {
    map:null,
    bounds:null
}
VX.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function() {
            var lat         = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng         = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
            VX.bounds.extend(point);                
            VX.map.fitBounds(VX.bounds);    //this works        
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: VX.map,
                zoom: 10,
                center: point
                });
            });
        });
        //VX.map.fitBounds(VX.bounds);      //this shows me the ocean east of Africa    
}
```

So basically my problem is that I can't figure out how to do fitbounds from outside of the .each function, and doing it inside the function calls it for every marker which looks bad.

I declare the bounds when I initialize the map... haven't included the entire code because its like 300 lines.

Shouldn't I be able to use a value that I passed to a global object?

Edit: ah, I was calling it from outside of the get function!

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted will work at all. `VX` doesn't have `bounds.extend` or `map.fitBounds` properties.

Comment: those are google maps api functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second call doesn't work because it is firing before the ajax `get()` returns.

Place the `fitBounds` inside the `get()` handler, but outside the `each()` function.  Like so:

```
var VX = {
    map:null,
    bounds:null
}
VX.placeMarkers = function(filename) 
{
    $.get
    (
        filename, 
        function(xml) 
        {
            $(xml).find("marker").each
            (
                function() 
                {
                    var lat         = $(this).find('lat').text();
                    var lng         = $(this).find('lng').text();
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

                    VX.bounds.extend(point);                
                    //VX.map.fitBounds(VX.bounds);    //this works        

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                    ({
                        position: point,
                        map: VX.map,
                        zoom: 10,
                        center: point
                    });
                }
            );
            VX.map.fitBounds(VX.bounds);    //-- This should work.
        }
    );  
    //VX.map.fitBounds(VX.bounds);      //this shows me the ocean east of africa    
}
```

Comment: wow, thats exactly it!
thanks :D

wish i had rep to upvote you :)